# Left Margin looks to be 0 in a div of review page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I did not found the duplicate, but if it is or False call - I'll delete the post.

Should the text be shifted to right a little bit? ("How to mantain" etc)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed, will be live after our next production build